# No bower_modules folder was created

Tags: node.js, knockout.js, yeoman, bower

Okay, so this is completely new terrain for me, so sorry if this is obvious!
I've been looking at Steven Sanderson's presentation from NDC 2014 (http://vimeo.com/97519516) and was trying to use that as a starting point for a new SPA I'm doing.

I've installed Node.js, yeoman, bower etc.

But when I run the "yo ko" command I get, almost, the same structure as in the demo, but I'm missing the "bower_modules" folder and content. No errors, no nothing.

Any idea to what it is I'm missing or doing wrong?

The demo isn't 100% clear on what modules/additional features it is he has installed.

Comment: Amazing I was doing the exact same thing and hit the same rock... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run in the console: bower install

Comment: That was the solution, first it failed, missing git in the PATH, when that was sorted, everything worked out fine! Thank you!